# Python parser not working with proxy what should I do?

Tags: python, parsing, proxy

i made a parser in python it works without a proxy but when i enable proxy it stops working. if it worked for you with another proxy, write a site from which you took the proxy and the proxy itself

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice

def parse():
        URL = 'https://2ip.ru/'
        
        proxies = {
            'http': 'http://168.61.33.21:80',
            'https': 'http://168.61.33.21:80',
        }

        response =  requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'ip-info_left')
        comps = []
 
        for item in items:
            comps.append({
                'title': item.find('div', class_='ip').find('span').get_text(strip=True)
                })
            for comp in comps:
                print(comp['title'])
parse()
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Is it throwing you some errors, or is it doing something different?

Comment: Yes error i cant add error to quation you can see error here https://qna.habr.com/q/910787